Polynomial division and remainder of
$f = x^{100}, g=(x-1)^2$
We know that $f=g\times q+r$ and I want to calculate the $r$, and $grad$ of $r$ is 1 or 0, because $grad(r) < grad(g)$.
If I write that $f=(x-1)(x-1)\times q + ax + b \implies a+b=1$
And that's all what I can do.
I’ve got this instruction: $f = (x-1)\times h +1$

If you are only interested in finding the remainder, write $x^{100}=((x-1)+1)^{100}$ and expand it using the binomial theorem.
